# Отсортировать список станций метро по расстоянию до пользователя

Tags: java, android

Еще раз всем привет.

Нашел проект на гитхабе про сортировку станций метро по близости к пользователю.

Вопрос такой: после запуска приложения на телефоне приложение ничего не показывает, в чем причина? Помогите исправить.

Это mainactivity.

**Обновление**

https://github.com/rovkinmax/LocationWithGooglePlayServices

Только в мейн активити, мне нужно, чтобы запускалось при запуске приложения, а не по щелчку.

Comment: Во-первых, уберите стены кода.

Во-вторых, выложите ссылку на гитхаб проекта.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот и не по клику. Все просто же.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        locationListener = LocationListenerGPServices.getInstance(this);
        locationListener.setLocationRunnable(this);
        startFind();

    }
```